# Youtube embed video start and end problem

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Youtube has a feature when you can embed a video and mark start and end time with it. It displays a frame on the seek bar and video starts from the starting mark and ends at the ending mark.

It stopped working a few weeks ago.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/h_8smKNoAAw?start=2285&end=2515

Here is a url that I am sure was working before.

Now it starts from point marked in the url, but it does not end at the ending mark.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: This is a serious issue, and we need more/updated answers to this problem.  For example, the following embed code does **not** work: `<iframe id="iframeStream" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4wpb_xwcG7E?start=134&end=150&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`.  However the link itself does work when literally copied and pasted into the URL bar.

Answer (score 9):

It just worked well for me.

I added the `autoplay=1` parameter in the URL you provided and the video actually starts and ends at the indicated positions.

Here is the modified URL:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/h_8smKNoAAw?start=2285&end=2515&autoplay=1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, although this causes the video to start and play at the correct time, it doesn't show any indication of the start and end times on the video player.

Comment: @Ardnived you have to use YouTube Iframe Player for that, if you post a new question, I might give it a try.